# Change the Encoding of the csv files uploaded to Wordpress media library to UTF-8

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, encoding

Hi I would like to have all my csv files that uploaded through Wordpress admin Media library auto convert the encording to utf-8.

I already search google and also find some filter and plugin in Wordpress but none of them seen to working on this.

What I can get is to edit and filter the uploaded files name before upload it to media library.
https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/rename-clean-wordpress-media-filenames

But what I needed is actually convert the csv files to utf-8 before it is being uploaded to the media library in Wordpress.

Anyone can help on this. Appreciate so much.

Comment: Hi anyone appreciate to help on this.

Comment: Allan, did you read the page I linked you? You actually need to make an attempt at solving the problem yourself. You can't just say "I want to do this" and expect other people to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for you info. I read the link. I already solved this by using the code below by checking the csv before upload.

```
$aluploads = wp_upload_dir(); 
$upload_path = $aluploads['path']; 
$str= file_get_contents(get_attached_file( $get_ID )); 

$str= mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE'); 
$new_file_name = $upload_path.'/hello.csv'; 
$str_converted = file_put_contents(get_attached_file( $get_ID ), $str);
```